Clarification on noexcept qualifier for wrapper functor using std::is_nothrow_invocable variants
I have a mini-personal library that I am creating and I have a wrapper functor I created in order to easily go from static invocable objects to functors.
For example, for something like std::unordered_map when using a custom hash xxhash, instead of wrapping the free-func xxhash in a functor manually, or having to use decltype in the signature, and pass the function pointer in the ctor (being a bit repetitive) as:
std::unordered_map<K, V, decltype(&xxhash)> map(&xxhash);
you could do:
std::unordered_map<K, V, func<xxhash>> map;
I have this component implemented as:
template <auto Fn>
struct func
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    decltype(auto)
    operator()(Ts&&... p_ts)
        const
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_r_v<
                    std::invoke_result_t<decltype(Fn), Ts&&...>,
                    decltype(Fn),
                    Ts&&...>)
    {
        return std::invoke(Fn, std::forward<Ts>(p_ts)...);
    }
};

My question is if return by value has any consideration on the noexcept clause. Depending on the calling context and definition the return value has a few possibilities on what happens to it (moved/copied, assigned/constructed) and any exception there would be outside the function. So my assumption is that the non _r_ version is sufficient (the repetition also makes me suspicious), but I'm not sure how to view the return clause more rigorously and realize I am getting to the actual mechanics of how return works in the abstract model of C++ which I may be likely to get wrong.
Can anybody provide some clarity on this point?
Edit: Additionally, I'm not sure RVO changes in C++17 changes anything here.

The noexcept on the operator is only about what the operator is doing, not the code calling the operator. If storing the return value involves a throwing conversion, that is someone else's problem.

I played around with this for a bit. That characterization only seems accurate if there is RVO. Since C++ 17 this is required, but modifying the code for C++ 14, it is possible to trigger a std::terminate because an exception was thrown in a noexcept function.
Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/cEdxqnTz6.
If you remove the -fno-elide-constructors then no std::terminate happens. So in the case of C++ 17, I believe that the _r_ does not have be used since any store of the return value will happen outside the function context (but without the RVO guarantee it is not sufficient).
